# Continuous Integration in Jenkins, Test Cases from 2 Builds are stacking up

Tags: jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

I have Continuous Integration Set up in Jenkins which is Triggered every time there is Code change, However if the change is done Frequently then the Test Cases from 2 Builds are stacking up. Is there a way to Cancel/Stop the Previous Builds Test Cases from Running, and just Continue with the latest Build

Comment: Are you using separate jobs for build and test?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the 'Quiet Period' option. This is available from the 'Advanced' section of 'Configure'.

Here, you can specify how many seconds Jenkins should wait before actually starting its task after a commit has been made. So, if you provide 30 minutes (30*60 = 1800) as the quiet period, and you have made a commit at 8PM, Jenkins would wait till 8:30 PM before starting its task. In the meantime, if you make 2-3 more commits, they will be stacked together and considered during the 8:30 PM run.

Hope this helps